# Better way of writing ratings php function

Tags: php, function

I've written this ratings function below and was wondering if it could be made smaller/simpler or better coded, it use shows an image based on percentage number within the function called

```
function rating( $number ) {

if ($number >= .0 && $number <= .099999) { 
  $star = '<img src="images/0.gif" alt="' . $number . '" />';
}

if ($number >= .10 && $number <= .199999){
  $star = '<img src="images/10.gif" alt="' . $number . '" />';
}

if ($number >= .20 && $number <= .299999){
  $star = '<img src="images/20.gif" alt="' . $number . '" />';
}

if ($number >= .30 && $number <= .399999){
  $star = '<img src="images/30.gif" alt="' . $number . '" />';
}

if ($number >= .40 && $number <= .499999){
  $star = '<img src="images/40.gif" alt="' . $number . '" />';
}

if ($number >= .50 && $number <= .599999){
  $star = '<img src="images/50.gif" alt="' . $number . '" />';
}

if ($number >= .60 && $number <= .699999) { 
  $star = '<img src="images/60.gif" alt="' . $number . '" />';
}

if ($number >= .70 && $number <= .799999){
  $star = '<img src="images/70.gif" alt="' . $number . '" />';
}

if ($number >= .80 && $number <= .899999){
  $star = '<img src="images/80.gif" alt="' . $number . '" />';
}

if ($number >= .90 && $number <= .999999){
  $star = '<img src="images/90.gif" alt="' . $number . '" />';
}

if ($number > .999999){
  $star = '<img src="images/100.gif" alt="' . $number . '" />';
}

return $star;
}
```

**heres how it is used:**

```
rating(0.51087)
```

Comment: Are you familiar with the switch function?  It won't work faster, but semantically, the mark-up will be easier to read.

Comment: @SableFoste: It probably would work faster in this case, if only by a very small amount.  The OP is checking every condition every time, whereas a `switch` would optimize a little more (closer to an `else if` construct).

Comment: @SableFoste: I am familiar with switch but how would I go about it, I mean what would the case be?

Comment: Please see @minitech's solution below.  If using a switch, you could use a similar switch/floor combination.  But his function is really most compact and best answers your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure, it just takes a little math.

```
function rating($number) {
    return '<img src="images/' . floor($number * 10) * 10 . '.gif" alt="' . $number . '" />';
}
```

Comment: This is the most compact solution. Of course, you could always reverse the situation and use ceil().